# I keep on getting a brownish-green hue around me

Tags: after-effects, adobe, greenscreen

I always get a brownish-green hue around me when I edit out the green screen in after effects. Is the problem the lighting, green screen editing, etc. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Lighting could definitely be part of the problem here. Typically, for green screen work, it helps to have a light between yourself and your green screen to get rid of those shadows behind you (sort of like a backlight).

To fix your current footage, I'd increase the sensitivity of your chroma key in After Effects, since it looks like AE is essentially leaving a thin outline of the screen around you. If you increase your tolerance, you should see that outline shrink a bit. Feathering the edges of your image can help with this, too.